# Filter Files in Directory.GetFiles

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a program that filters every single file that has an extension `*.txt` in a certain folder and its sub-folders and adds it to the `ListBox`.

```
Dim Directories As New IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\Users\" & SystemInformation.UserName & "\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft")
Dim Directory As IO.DirectoryInfo
Dim File As IO.FileInfo

For Each Directory In Directories.GetDirectories
    For Each File In Directory.GetFiles
        ListBox1.Items.Add(File.Name)
        Next
    Next
```

The problem is that I can't filter the extension, I get all the files in the folder, and its sub-folders.
I am trying to filter ("*.txt"), but I can't make it work, I always get an error.
Sorry if this is simple, but I'm a newbie on VB.Net.

Comment: `i can't filter the extension`  doesnt look like there is any code trying to filter    [Directory.EnumerateFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above, you need to let your code know that you only want to display .txt files.
The following code below should do just that for you.

```
Dim Directories As New IO.DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & "\.minecraft"
Dim fileInfo = Directories.GetFiles("*.txt", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)

For Each file In fileInfo
    ListBox1.Items.Add(file.Name)
Next
```

Keep in mind, depending on where you are searching, you might need to have **administrator privileges**